# Comportamiento de std::is_constructible con PODs

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

Considerando el siguiente código:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct POD_t
{
    int value { };
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<POD_t, int>, "No!!!");
    return 0;
}
```

No compila con el estándar c++17 en los compiladores gcc, clang y msvc
pero si compila con el estándar c++20 en los compiladores gcc y msvc menos en clang.

¿Por qué pasa esto? y ¿Qué alternativas hay para saber si un pod es construible en el estándar de c++17?
Aquí la [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oYa617Eqq).

**Editado**:

Bueno, viendo el soporte para el estándar de c++20 en: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support clang aun no tiene implementado *"Parenthesized initialization of aggregates"* y seria por eso que no compila en clang con el estándar de c++20.

¿Por qué no compila en c++17?
debe ser porque en la implementación de is_constructible usan () envés de {} para llamar al constructor.

¿Qué alternativas hay para saber si un pod es construible en el estándar de c++17?
Bueno, buscando una implementación de std::is_constructible encontre [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38181716/12567005), y solo cambie los paréntesis por llaves y ya funciona, aquí la otra [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/M3Pn3os1x).

Comment: Tengo el presentimiento de que es mas problema del compilador que del estandar

Answer (score 0):

Por desgracia y a pesar de su nombre `std::is_constructible` no comprueba si un tipo arbitrario es construible con los tipos facilitados, como puede verse en [la documentación de cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types) lo que hace es comprobar si dispone de un constructor para esos tipos:

| Supported operations |  |
| --- | --- |
| `is_constructible` (C++11) | checks if a type **has a constructor** for specific arguments (class template) |
| `is_trivially_constructible` (C++11) | checks if a type **has a constructor** for specific arguments (class template) |
| `is_nothrow_constructible` (C++11) | checks if a type **has a constructor** for specific arguments (class template) |

De hecho, podemos comprobar que si añades un constructor el código no falla:

```
struct POD_t
{
    POD_t(int) { }
    int value { };
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<POD_t, int>, "No!!!"); // Sin problemas!
    return 0;
}
```